# Is dark matter inside galaxies different from dark matter in intergalactic space?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies

I just read a text about astronomy and when talking about dark matter the author says:

> [...], the dark matter responsible for the orbits of the stars in the Milky Way is probably different from the dark matter responsible for the orbit of the Milky Way within the local super-cluster of galaxies.

Is this true? How would it be different? And why?

For context, this is the whole paragraph:

> Since the 1930's astronomers have measured the orbits of galaxies in clusters of galaxies, clusters of galaxies in clusters of clusters, and so forth. They have found similar anomalies in the angular velocity of galaxies at these larger scales. Again the anomalous high angular velocities of the galaxies and clusters of galaxies may be explained by postulating a mysterious dark matter that fills the universe. It is doubtful that one can explain the anomalous angular velocities at different scales by the same type of dark matter. Thus, the dark matter responsible for the orbits of the stars in the Milky Way is probably different from the dark matter responsible for the orbit of the Milky Way within the local super-cluster of galaxies.

And the article can be found here:
https://mathblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Keplers-New-Astronomy.pdf

Comment: As far as I know, this is not a mainstream view. In general, you don’t want to read about physics on math blogs. In the standard cosmological model, there is only one kind of dark matter.

Comment: Well in his defense, the rest of the text is an interesting review of Kepler's work and, according to the article, the author is a Ph. D.

Comment: This may be a reference to the variaous musing on the possibility of there being both warm and cold populations of dark matter present. I haven't the faintest idea how seriously those musing are taken right now. There was a point when they were, if not actually accepted, at least something serious people could talk about.

Comment: Well, the standard model (for now) is called Lambda-*Cold*-Dark-Matter. I do not know of any compelling evidence for warm or hot dark matter. I agree that their possible existence has been considered, as have more complicated models with combinations. However, these uglier models do not seem to be necessary to explain the observational data.

Comment: There are a lot of wrong statements coming from PhDs. Getting a degree doesn't magically make you infallible. You remain almost exactly as fallible about everything outside the very very narrow domain of your PhD as before.

Comment: @knzhou, I couldn't agree more with you on this. LOL! +1

Comment: @knzhou The higher degree people get, the deeper their misconceptions become *inside* their narrow domain.

Comment: I should have added this before: being a contrarian _without_ an advanced degree doesn't make you infallible _either_. Nothing does. Understanding what's correct is a hard task for anyone. It shouldn't be taken lightly.

Comment: @Chegon Both types are exactly the same - neither exists. The dark matter idea is dead due to its lack of predictive ability. Explaining things after the fact is not enough for a scientific theory. Another reason is no viable dark matter candidates in the Standard Model.

Comment: @safesphere Why would you make a false assertion like that? The existence of dark matter is generally accepted by the scientific community. The alternatives are more speculative. What’s *your* explanation for the evidence pointing to dark matter?

Comment: @user76284 (1) Truth in science is defined by observation. There is not a shred of direct observational evidence for "dark energy or matter", only theoretical speculations. (2) I am not aware of any governing body in physics empowered to define what is "accepted". (3) Science is not decided by a democratic vote. (4) One doesn't need to have a different explanation to point out a wrong theory. (5) You can start opening your mind with the link in the answer by TonyK below and other posts by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabine_Hossenfelder - a well known theoretical physicist in Frankfurt.

Comment: @user76284 Here she gives a good objective talk on what "dark matter" is and whether or not it may exist: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FN2d2cmi_Gk&list=PLwgQsqtH9H5duzw0MlJuJjwGNSMPUjHy2&index=4&t=0s

Comment: @safesphere The false assertion you made is “The dark matter idea is *dead*” (which is plainly false), not “The dark matter idea is *correct*” (which nobody knows). Do you understand the difference? None of your points are relevant to the first. Sabine herself concludes: “The situation is that dark matter works well in some cases and modified gravity works better in other cases... The answer may be a combination of the two.” So, would you like to retract your false claim that the dark matter idea is “dead”?

Comment: @user76284 You are taking it out of context. I said it was dead, because it could not be used for predictions. For every galaxy you can figure the distribution of "dark matter" that would explain the rotation - after the fact. Sure you can fit a curve to any set of data points. However, you cannot use the "dark matter" idea to *predict* the galaxy rotation and test it by observation. An idea without the power of prediction is unfalsifiable, so it is not science. In any case, this is my opinion, which doesn't stop you from investing in "dark matter", if you want.

Comment: Isn't the very nature of dark matter (or the dark matter idea) that _we don't know_ and probably cannot know any time soon because all we know is _something something, unexplainable gravity_, and dark matter which presumably is _something weird, non baryonic_ gives at least _some_ explanation for that gravity? But even disregarding practcial issues (astronomic distances), seeing how it probably isn't even composed like anything we know (or we'd have a way of somehow seeing it), how can we make any qualified claims about it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard model of cosmology (for now) is called [Lambda-Cold-Dark-Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model). It has only *one* kind of dark matter, and it agrees well with the observational data.

Other types of dark matter, such as “warm” or “hot” rather than “cold”, have been considered, and some people have considered models in which more than one kind of dark matter exist. These more complicated models do not appear to be necessary to explain what we observe.

The precise nature of dark matter doesn’t matter in cosmology. What matters is the relationship between its energy density and its pressure, because in General Relativity both energy density and pressure cause gravity. What is important is how *relativistic* dark matter is, because that determines its pressure. Cold dark matter is *non*-relativistic and has negligible pressure. All of its gravity comes from its energy density.

Answer (score 14):

Others have made the point that the current concordance cosmology includes only one variety of dark matter, which is cold. This is correct.

If dark matter is indeed some as-yet unknown particle, it would be surprising if it was the *only* unknown particle. The standard model of particle physics is basically complete, without room for extra particles without changing some of the underlying principles. There are some anomalies which point to our knowledge of particle physics being incomplete, so eventually discoveries will likely be made. Anyway, all this is to say that there are probably many species of dark particles, but it is currently thought (mostly by invocation of Occam's razor) that the 'astrophysical dark matter', the stuff that explains the motions within and between galaxies, is either predominantly due to one particle, or a family of particles which behave similarly as far as the relevant astrophysics is concerned.

Now I hesitate to make this next point in this way, but I think there is some merit to the statement that dark matter isn't "the same" on all scales. The standard cold dark matter has been hugely successful in explaining the physics of the large scale Universe, but fails in some areas on small scales. There are other examples of ideas to explain astrophysical dark matter which work very well on small scales but struggle on large scales. One example is the modified gravity theory MOND. I bring up this particular theory only because there is a nice, reasonably accessible article contrasting it and LCDM available here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7525

As yet no one theory has succeeded in explaining the dark matter effect on all scales, which is why we still have an astrophysical dark matter problem, in addition to the question of what particle dark matter might be.

So I agree with some interpretation of (the spirit of?) the statement, but I don't think it was especially well articulated in the article cited in the question.

Comment: "*As yet no one theory has succeeded in explaining the dark matter effect on all scales*" - Has TeVeS been falsified?

Comment: @safesphere TeVeS, at least the simpleet formulation, made a strong prediction thay gravitational waves do not propagate at the speed of light. The LIGO measurements with optical counterparts strongly rule out the theory.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody knows what dark matter is, or even whether it exists (see for instance [this link](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2019/10/dark-matter-nightmare-what-if-we-just.html)). So asking how many kinds of dark matter there are is like asking how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.